# Tables cut on the right hand side

Tags: javascript, css, printing

When I print my documents stored in  my application the tables in the document with size more than 630px are been cut on the right hand side. I tried with the following code to limit the table size

```
<style>
  @media print{
    #sb-content table{max-width:630px !important}
    #sb-content{position:static!important;}
  }
</style>
```

But this is not working! Please help! The issue occurs only while printing!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are setting the `max-width` to 630px.

Change it or remove it!

```
@media print {
  #sb-content table{max-width: 630px !important}
  #sb-content{position: static !important;}
}
```

Here you can see, that you are setting the `max-width: 630px !important`. Which is why, the file is printed from left to right (to an extend of 630px width) and then remaining part is left.

Try changing it to lets say: `max-width: 100% !important;` to the `body` element. To that the body is fully covered and the table takes a percentage of the body as

```
#sb-content table {max-width: 80% !important}
```

But the general issue would be the cell spacing, margins, paddings etc.

Comment: max-width: 100% !important; is also not working!!!In the document there are tables of width more than 630px.I want to limit the size to 630px.Please suggest!!!

Comment: Then you can use `100%` width for them, since `px` might not always work :)

Comment: I cannot edit the documents as their are thousands of them.I have to limit their size only while printing.When the documents are viewed the tables are fitting fine in the screen.

Comment: #sb-content table {max-width: 80% !important} I tried this but it is not working. If i give #sb-content table {width: 630px !important} it is working but some of the tables whose size is less than 200px are enlarged and looking bad!!!

Comment: Try giving some classnames to these tables and then use it!

Comment: Since their are Thousands of documents it is not possibe to do any changes in the tables.But all the documents have a common div #sbcontent.

Comment: And also the tables are spilt into two pages and in some cases the last line of the page is spilt like one half in one page and the other half in other page